# Push a notification from Android app to Gear 2 (Tizen)?

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I can't seem to find a document on how to push to Gear2 from my Android app. The closest I can find is this tutorial on building the Integrated app, but it's a fetching scheme (data only transferred when the user presses a button on the watch) http://developer.samsung.com/events/developer-blog/blog/Tutorial-How-to-build-a-Basic-Integrated-Gear-Application

So I'm wondering is the push is done via standard Android Wearable Notification, like here ? http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

or any pointer to documents?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/SamsungGearApplication_UIDesignGuideline_1.0.pdf.

section 3.4
Notifications app section.

I don't think any code is necessary (though I haven't tested this myself)
The default behaviour is to push all notifications, but it can be controlled using Gear Manager App.